# Organisation Policies | restrictVpcPeering and kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I want to have VPC peering denied over whole organisation. Currently it is implemented with organisation policy `constraints/compute.restrictVpcPeering` set to deny all.

Unfortunately, as a part of kubernetes cluster creation over shared vpc, there is some peering done to the subnets on google side (according to [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-shared-vpc)). I would like to lose up my constrains, so those could be allowed, but I couldn't find the way to only allow those yet.

Subnets on GCP side has resource path like this:

```
network projects/gke-prod-europe-west3-XXXX/global/networks/gke-ndaXXXXXYYYYYZZZZ-ZZZZ-YYY-net
```

where XYZ are random.

At first I wanted to use [`under:` notation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints) to allow all peering with networks in `under:projects/gke-prod-europe-west3-*` but looks like wildcard is not supported format there.

Is there known `organization_id` that google k8s resource fall under? Or there is other way that I'm missing?

Original error:

```
Constraint constraints/compute.restrictVpcPeering violated for project 1234567890. Peering the network projects/gke-prod-europe-west3-XXXX/global/networks/gke-ndaXXXXXYYYYYZZZZ-ZZZZ-YYY-net is not allowed.
```

Comment: Can you explain in more details what are you trying to achieve ? Do you want to be able to permit VPC peering with just a few projects regardless of the "deny" organization policy ?

Comment: The goal is to allow all projects in organisation to use kubernetes, but deny all VPC peering. As this one peering is dependency of kubernetes deploymeny (?), I need to create an exception.

Comment: One more detail, this is about private clusters.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can use any wildcard characters; you need to specify project id's by name one by one - no other way around it.

If you have a look at the "[Constraints for specific services](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints#constraints-for-specific-services)" documentation:

> This list constraint defines the set of VPC networks that are allowed to be peered with the VPC networks belonging to this project, folder, or organization. By default, a Network Admin for one network can peer with any other network. The allowed/denied list of networks must be identified in the form: `under:organizations/ORGANIZATION_ID`, `under:folders/FOLDER_ID`, `under:projects/PROJECT_ID`, or `projects/PROJECT_ID/global/networks/NETWORK_NAME`.
> `constraints/compute.restrictVpcPeering`

You can however request to implement this feature, you can do this by raising a new issue on [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Answer (score 0):

From this [Medium post](https://autonomousthingz-life.medium.com/google-cloud-organisation-policies-get-the-restrict-vpc-peering-usage-organisation-policy-d87dce84a5e7) I would add the below allowed folders:

```
# Required for the use of Cloud SQL
- under:folders/1087601843002  # google.com/products/speckle/
# Required if projects use GKE private clusters.
- under:folders/391150242170  # google.com/tenancy-units/gke/prod
```